# Replace unicode with actual data in php

Tags: php, html, unicode

I want to **replace** unicode **\u00a0** with actual data in **php**.

Example : `"<b>Sort By\u00a0-\u00a0</b><a href="http://pagalworld.com/files/9704/Dil Dhadakne Do (2015) Mp3 Songs/atoz/1.html">A to Z\u00a0|\u00a0</a><a href="http://pagalworld.com/files/9704/Dil Dhadakne Do (2015) Mp3 Songs/recent/1.html">Recently Added\u00a0|\u00a0</a><a href="http://pagalworld.com/files/9704/Dil Dhadakne Do (2015) Mp3 Songs/downloads/1.html">Most Downloaded</a>"`

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: `"Sort By\u00a0"` → What do you mean, (1) the string contains the sequence `\u00a0` (6 characters), or (2) the string contains a non-breaking space (1 character)?

Answer (score 2):

[\u00a0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) is the [escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C) of a `NO-BREAK SPACE`

To decode **any** `escape sequence` in `PHP` you can use this function:

```
function unicodeString($str, $encoding=null) {
    if (is_null($encoding)) $encoding = ini_get('mbstring.internal_encoding');
    return preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/u', create_function('$match', 'return mb_convert_encoding(pack("H*", $match[1]), '.var_export($encoding, true).', "UTF-16BE");'), $str);
}
echo unicodeString($str);
//<b>Sort By - </b><a href="http://pagalworld.com/files/9704/Dil Dhadakne Do (2015) Mp3 Songs/atoz/1.html">A to Z | </a><a href="http://pagalworld.com/files/9704/Dil Dhadakne Do (2015) Mp3 Songs/recent/1.html">Recently Added | </a><a href="http://pagalworld.com/files/9704/Dil Dhadakne Do (2015) Mp3 Songs/downloads/1.html">Most Downloaded</a>
```

---

DEMO:

https://ideone.com/9QtzMO

---

If you just need to replace a **single** `escape sequence`, use:

```
$str = str_replace("\u00a0", " ", $str);
echo $str;
<b>Sort By - </b><a href="http://pagalworld.com/files/9704/Dil Dhadakne Do (2015) Mp3 Songs/atoz/1.html">A to Z | </a><a href="http://pagalworld.com/files/9704/Dil Dhadakne Do (2015) Mp3 Songs/recent/1.html">Recently Added | </a><a href="http://pagalworld.com/files/9704/Dil Dhadakne Do (2015) Mp3 Songs/downloads/1.html">Most Downloaded</a>
```

Comment: Note the first function doesn't replace a single unicode character, but it replaces an escape sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the function!! Saved my life!

Comment: I found that this only replace the first found emoji. How do I replace all emojis in the String? and it also doesn't replace some emojis such as \ud83d\udc9 ()