# Converting a String unicode representation of emoji in SQL to the actual Emoji in Dart (or in PHP)

Tags: php, flutter, dart, unicode, emoji

I have spent the whole day and night on this. Many answers from many people but none of which works for my case. Sorry for the noob question but I literally have spent whole yesterday until early morning for this.

So I got an old system to migrate to a new one.
Essentially from SQL server to Firebase. With a new structure, all new uid and the client wants the unicode data from old SQL server to be converted to the real emojis.

So it goes from SQL (in old server) => PHP (in old server to fetch the SQL data) => Flutter (in my laptop) => Firebase (Firestore).

In the SQL server there are strings like this for example:
`Spring... fall...\ud83d\udc90...flowers!`

Then the PHP code that retrieved from the SQL database return it like this:

```
// Create Connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysqli_set_charset($conn,'utf8mb4');
    
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$result = $conn->query($sql);
    
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $db_data = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $db_data[] = $row;
    }

    // Send back the complete records as a json
    echo json_encode($db_data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}else{
    http_response_code(405);
    echo "Query error";
}
$result->free();
$conn->close();
return;
```

In Dart (Flutter Web) I got the data like this:

```
final response = await http.get(urlRequest);

final rawRows = jsonDecode(response.body) as List<dynamic>;
  
rawRows.forEach((map) => print(map['description']));
```

This prints out: `Spring... fall...\ud83d\udc90...flowers!`

What I want is `Spring... fall......flowers!`

I did a hardcoded print test (i.e: `print('Spring... fall...\ud83d\udc90...flowers!');` and it gives exactly the result I want (i.e: It turns `\ud83d\udc90` part of the string to )

I have tried sending it as is to Firebase, it still doesn't recognize `\ud83d\udc90` as emojis. It was stored in Firebase like this `Spring... fall...\ud83d\udc90...flowers!`. Which is totally understandable, I guess we need to convert it first.

I also have tried using converter in the PHP side like this: ([thanks to Pedro Lobito](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32990255/12435337))

```
function unicodeString($str, $encoding=null) { 
    if (is_null($encoding)) $encoding = ini_get('mbstring.internal_encoding');
    return preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/u', create_function('$match', 'return mb_convert_encoding(pack("H*", $match[1]), '.var_export($encoding, true).', "UTF-16BE");'), $str);
}
```

Then the `$db_data[] = $row;` part in the PHP changed to `$db_data[] = unicodeString($row);`

But this solution only works for some emojis but not for all emojis, such as the case of  above. It shows `Spring... fall...?...flowers!` instead.

So now I want to try to convert it in Dart instead since I'm more familiar with it. Unless someone could help to solve it in PHP as well.

Comment: Wow they've overridden `window.print`? That's crazy. I don't know dart, but I found that `print` *(which overrides window.print since window is implicit)* prints a String representation of an Object.

Comment: Yes. It shows the emoji in the Debug Console of VS Code (Flutter). (And Android Studio probably too)

Comment: I would recommend: 1. Clearly define what formats/encodings are expected at each step.  Exactly what does the SQL database store?  UTF-8 strings?  UTF-16 strings?  ASCII strings with escaped Unicode characters?  From your original example, it sounds like Unicode characters are escaped, so you literally get a string with a sequence of ``\``, `u`, `d`, `8`, `3`, `d` characters.  However, your update makes it seem like it stores actual Unicode strings.  Which is it?  Or is data stored inconsistently?

Comment: 2. Instead of printing strings, examine the actual *bytes*.  Printing each byte in hexadecimal probably might make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I don't remember exactly why that happened (the updated part, because probably I was too tired) so I better delete it than making any confusion. About the data type. From SQL it was set to `utf8mb4`. In PHP it returns from `json_encode`, I believe it is `UTF-8`.

Comment: So when you get strings from your database, do get UTF-8 strings directly, or do you get escaped strings?  You should verify at each stage that you get the bytes you expect, and then you can identify at which stage things go wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think the strings coming from SQL supposed to be a purely unescaped strings I believe but I couldn't confirmed it right now because need to catch deadline. Does `mysqli_set_charset($conn,'utf8mb4');` imply anything about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after working a couple of days I worked on my own solution.

So what I did was to use `RegEx` to detect the sequence in the String and replace them with emojis.

1. Declare Regular expressions for detecting the unicodes (in my case the unicode is something like (\uXXX):

```
// To detect a single unicode
static const regEx1 = '\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})'; 

// To detect a 2-bytes unicode
static const regEx2 = '$regEx1$regEx1';
```

2. Create a method to detect each RegEx. Then when a pattern is found, replace it with `jsonDecode` with added quotes in there. Like this `jsonDecode('"${match.group(0)}"');`.

The code:

```
static String _regExEmojiUnicode(String text, String regEx) {
  final regexCheck = RegExp(regEx, caseSensitive: false);
  String newText = '';
  int _lastEndText = 0;
  int _lastEndNewText = 0;

  regexCheck.allMatches(text).forEach((match) {
    final start = match.start;
    final end = match.end;

    final String replacement = jsonDecode('"${match.group(0)}"');
      
    String startString;
    newText == ''
        ? startString = '${text.substring(0, start)}$replacement'
        : startString =
            '${newText.substring(0, _lastEndNewText)}${text.substring(_lastEndText, start)}$replacement';

    _lastEndNewText = startString.length;
    _lastEndText = end;

    newText =
        '$startString${text.substring(end)}';
      
  });

  if(newText == '') newText = text;

  return newText;
}
```

3. Create a method to check for the different cases of emojis:

```
static String replaceEmoji(String text) {
  String newText = text;

  // Checking for 2-bytes and single bytes emojis
  if(newText.contains('\\u'))
    newText = _regExEmojiUnicode(newText, regEx2);
  if(newText.contains('\\u'))
    newText = _regExEmojiUnicode(newText, regEx1);

  return newText;
}
```

Then this works!!

I did this in haste, so if there is any improvements can be made to the RegEx patterns or anywhere else in the code, I'm open to any suggestions.

Thank you